# How to fix "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager Error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I upgraded the library version of `react-navigation` and its utility libraries. Now when running the application it gives me **"RNCSafeAreaProvider was not found in the UIManager Error"**. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Try the below link steps; [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849665/react-native-react-navigation-safearea-issue/75379874#75379874)

Comment: This answer helped me out after spending many many hours trying to figure this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75379874/5394779

Answer (score 2):

This error might come when you upgrade the version of `react-navigation` library, it's dependencies and linked modules. As mentioned in the [react-navigation doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/getting-started/) , it is made up of some more core utilities.

The issue can be there because of,

1. Some needed libraries are not installed.
2. The Library versions of these connected modules are not compatible
   with each other (probably when manually upgrading libraries )
3. A clean rebuild is required

### STEP 01 - Install Utility Libraries .

As mentioned in the React Navigation documentation try installing the rest of the needed libraries.

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

### STEP 02 - Fixing incompatible versions

> You shouldn't be worrying about this step if you didn't have those
> utility libraries installed in the first place. Move forward to step
> 03 :)

Now if the React-Native app was working before updating the versions and not anymore, that could be because of incompatible react-navigation and other utility library versions. Easiest way to fix this is...

```
npm remove react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

then...

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

This should fix any incompatible version issues introduced during the upgrading process.

### STEP 03 - Build App Again

Since I tried this fix in an Android build environment...

1. Uninstall the app.
2. `cd android` android folder and type `./gradlew clean`
3. `npx react-native run-android`to build the app again.

**The "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager Error should be gone by now ;)**